# Simultaneous congruence relations $x^a \equiv 1\pmod p$ and $x^b \equiv 1\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Let $x$ be a natural number and $p$ a positive prime such that $\gcd(x, p)=1$. If $x^a \equiv 1\pmod p$ and $x^b \equiv 1\pmod p$, can we derive a relation between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: $\gcd(a,b)$ is divisible by $\text{ord}_x(p)$.

Comment: Yes, I think that's all we get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gcd condition that MXYMXY stated is the most general possible.

Your equations imply that that $x^{b\pm a} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, which happens if and only if $\mathrm{ord}(x)\mid b\pm a$. This, of course is equivalent to $\mathrm{ord}(x) \mid a$ and $\mathrm{ord}(x)\mid b$, which is in turn equivalent to $\mathrm{ord}(x)\mid \gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: What if $x^a \equiv 1\pmod p$ and $x^a \equiv 1\pmod q$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes and $\gcd(x, p)=\gcd(x,q)=1$? What can we say about $p$ and $q$?

Comment: For the case where $a = 2$, or perhaps more generally if $a$ is even, the most general relation you could find is probably [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity). For $a$ odd, I don't believe there is a simple relation between $p$ and $q$. There are some other higher reciprocity theorems, but they become progressively (and rapidly) more complicated.

Comment: One more question! Let suppose $a$ is even. Then what will be the relation between $p$ and $q$ using quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: @Ghartal Sorry, now that I think about your condition more closely, quadratic reciprocity probably won't say much. For your particular question, the most we can say is probably that $p \mid x^a - 1$ and $q \mid x^a - 1$ so that $pq \mid x^a - 1$. This in turn implies that $a\mid (p-1)(q-1)$ via Euler's totient theorem. I don't think we can get anything more restrictive than that.

Comment: No problem EuYu. Are you sure about that? I mean how you conclude from $pq|x^a-1$ that $a|\phi(pq)$?

Comment: @Ghartal $pq\mid x^a -1$ means that $x^a \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$. This happens if and only if $a\mid \phi(pq)$.